# How to find which display/window manager etc I am using?

Tags: debian, xfce, window-manager, desktop, budgie

I am working on Debian Stable Linux with XFCE4 which is running very well. When I start the computer it straight away starts XFCE4 GUI desktop.

Now I want to install Budgie desktop and would like to choose which desktop to go to. However, I do not know what display/window is installed. How can I find this out change so that instead of going automatically to XFCE4, I get to choose which desktop to go to? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to find the window manager you're using is by running either `neofetch` or `screenfetch`. If not installed, at least one of them should be available in your repo. In the exemplary screenshot below, both show that my window manager is Xfwm4.

[image: Screenshot of neofetch and screenfetch outputs with the WM listing highlighted]

Comment: Both Neofetch and Screenfetch are available in Debian repositories. I installed Neofetch and it showed my WM also to be Xfwm4 (must be XFCE4 default).